# addEventListener and onclick Function do not work

Tags: html, onclick

Using onclick and adding an event listener to my button does not correctly call the function.

How can I call my function through a button press in the HTML.
I also have jquery added so am able to use jquery syntax aswell.

```
document.getElementById("fName-group").addEventListener("click", writeFName, false);
function writeFName(fName-group) {
localStorage.setItem('fName-group', fName-group);
var cfmF = confirm("Did you mean to enter: \n" + fName-group + '?');
if (cfmF) {
    console.log(fName-group);
    window.alert('Success!');
    var theEmail1 = localStorage.getItem('fName-group');
    document.getElementById("theEmail1").innerHTML = theEmail1;
    console.log(theEmail1);
}
else {
    window.alert('Please Re-Enter Data');
}
}


    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3> Add new email</h3>
    <form id="emailInputForm">
        <div class="fName-group">

            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName_Input" placeholder="Enter candidate 
            first name ...">
            <div class="email-group-append">
                <input type="button" id ="fName_But"value="Submit First Name">

                <p id="emailOutput"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: `fName-group` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited somewhere in your code, such as:

- Using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `document.getElementById`.
- Correcting `id`s (`fName_But` instead of `fName-group`, `emailOutput` instead of `theEmail1`) in your js code.
- Editing the way to get value from the input before alerting.

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#fName_But").addEventListener("click", writeFName, false);

function writeFName() {

    var fNameGroup = document.querySelector('#fName_Input').value;

    localStorage.setItem('fName-group', fNameGroup);

    var cfmF = confirm("Did you mean to enter: \n" + fNameGroup + '?');

    if (cfmF) {
        console.log(fNameGroup);
        window.alert('Success!');

        var theEmail1 = localStorage.getItem('fName-group');

        document.querySelector("#emailOutput").innerHTML = theEmail1;
        console.log(theEmail1);
    } else {
        window.alert('Please Re-Enter Data');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3> Add new email</h3>
    <form id="emailInputForm">
        <div class="fName-group">

            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName_Input" placeholder="Enter candidate first name ...">
            <div class="email-group-append">
                <input type="button" id="fName_But" value="Submit First Name">

                <p id="emailOutput"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is claiming "cannot add property addeventlistener of null"

Comment: @cola465 Make sure you're defining event for `#fName_But`, not `fName-group`. Just copy all of the code from my answer and run it.

Comment: I have copied the code and pasted it, yet it still refuses to run and claims "cannot add property addeventlistener of null".                                                                         I am fairly new to coding and am sure the issue lies somewhere else in my code, if you could have a read through and give me tips on where I am mucking up it would be very appreciated. : https://www.codepile.net/pile/nkzNLgk8

Comment: @cola465 I've tested with the code you've refered, it's working fine. There is no error message like that. This is the [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/4119g3C/Screen-Shot-2020-01-12-at-22-03-32.png)

Comment: @cola465 Or maybe you're running the old code which made the error message. The code which contained `fName-group` and `lName-group`...

Comment: Thank you it works fine now, just had to use a different IDE. Following on from this can I use the fNameGroup local storage data in other functions or can it only be used within its functions scope. As I need the input data to be saved to a variable so I can pass it to an API